# ActivityManager getRunningTasks not working on Lollipop?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

If you want to get activity "on top", you call `getRunningTasks(1)` on `ActivityManager`, and you will get something like `com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity` in result.TopActivity.ClassName.

But I just tried it on Nexus 5 with Android 5, and no matter what app is on top (chrome, maps, home screen..), i get `com.google.android.launcher.GEL`

Is this some breaking change? Is this documented somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this some breaking change?

Yes.

> Is this documented somewhere?

[Yes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks%28int%29).